# What type of query do NamedQueries use?

Tags: java, sql

I'm using netbean's option to create entity classes from database and i'm not really used to this "dialect" for a query and i wanted to learn more about it's syntax. Can someone tell me what's the name of the "dialect" or syntax of this query?

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUserId", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userId = :userId")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByName", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.name= :name")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findBySurname", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.surname= :surname")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.email = :email")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByDateOfBirth", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.dateob= :dateob")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.password= :password")})
```

Comment: That is called JPQL. If you're using JPA, you should probably start reading a bit about it. Your class should be named User, BTW, not Users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not SQL, it is JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language), which is defined in the JPA (Java Persistence API) specification.

Implementations of JPA (eg Hibernate) will transform this to an SQL query in the right SQL dialect for the data source they are accessing.